# displaying image in opencv

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am writing a simple program for displaying image in a window, but when running it is not loading the image. I am not getting why this is happening?

```
#include<opencv/cvaux.h>
#include<opencv/highgui.h>
#include<opencv/cxcore.h>
#include<opencv/cv.h>


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, CHAR* argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\Users\jai guru umesh\Desktop\6.jpg");

  if (!img)
  {
    printf("Image can NOT Load!!!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  cvNamedWindow("myfirstwindow");
  cvShowImage("myfirstwindow", img);

  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&img);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did the image actually load? Try putting `if (!img) printf("Image load failed\n");` on the line after `cvLoadImage()`

Comment: NO, image is also not loading in the program. I don't know why??

Answer (score 3):

`\` is an escape character.

Change

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\Users\jai guru umesh\Desktop\6.jpg");
```

to

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\jai guru umesh\\Desktop\\6.jpg");
```

or

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/jai guru umesh/Desktop/6.jpg");
```